# Using Custom Dataset With nprtool

Tags: matlab

Am trying to clasify objects using neural networks' `nprtool` in MATLAB. However, loading the data (input and outputs) is my problem. I have gone through the given examples in the documentation but am not able to customize the inputs and outputs. Part of the dataset is given below for your reference; assume that the data is already normalized. How can one use the the MATLAB Neural Network Toolbox `nprtool` with custom data like these?

```
% Small vehicles
XS1 = 1.0e+03 *[3.2730    0.0712    0.0614        5.1480]; % frame 167
XS2 = 1.0e+03 *[4.4680    0.0869    0.0668        6.2370];% frame 555
XS3 = 1.0e+03 *[2.5450    0.0742    0.0659        4.6900]; % frame 780
XS4 = 1.0e+03 *[1.9830    0.0617    0.0477        2.9680]; % frame 826
XS5 = 1.0e+03 *[2.9090    0.0630    0.0610        4.1600]; % frame 880
XS6 = 1.0e+03 *[3.8460    0.0797    0.0640        5.6700]; % frame 1283

% Medium vehicles
XM1 = 1.0e+03 *[4.7770    0.0981    0.0663        6.9560]; % frame 167
XM2 = 1.0e+03 *[5.1050    0.0997    0.0678        7.4460]; % frame 430
XM3 = 1.0e+03 *[4.0240    0.0846    0.0619        5.4780]; % frame 2020
XM4 = 1.0e+03 *[6.9750    0.1165    0.0794        9.6280]; % frame 2982
XM5 = 1.0e+03 *[5.2040    0.1063    0.0652        7.0810]; % frame 3081
XM6 = 1.0e+03 *[3.2830    0.0733    0.0645        4.6080]; % frame 4314

% Large vehicles
XL1 = 1.0e+04 *[1.0092    0.0148    0.0089        1.4948]; % frame 1340
XL2 = 1.0e+04 *[0.9351    0.0129    0.0096        1.2444]; % frame 1375
XL3 = 1.0e+04 *[0.6021    0.0141    0.0095        1.5096]; % frame 1625
XL4 = 1.0e+04 *[0.8734    0.0143    0.0086        1.1868]; % frame 1679
XL5 = 1.0e+04 *[1.0773    0.0141    0.0100        1.4933]; % frame 2204
XL6 = 1.0e+04 *[0.8491    0.0118    0.0097        1.0556]; % frame 3535

% CONCATANATING THE OBJECT FEATURES
XS = [XS1;XS2;XS3;XS4;XS5;XS6];
XM = [XM1;XM2;XM3;XM4;XM5;XM6];
XL = [XL1;XL2;XL3;XL4;XL5;XL6];

%  inputs matrix
X = [XS;XM;XL];

%% OUTPUTS
YS ={'smallvehicle';'smallvehicle';'smallvehicle';'smallvehicle';'smallvehicle';'smallvehicle'};
YM ={'mediumvehicle';'mediumvehicle';'mediumvehicle';'mediumvehicle';'mediumvehicle';'mediumvehicle'};
YL ={'largevehicle';'largevehicle';'largevehicle';'largevehicle';'largevehicle';'largevehicle'};

% outputs matrix
Y = [YS;YM;YL];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [MATLAB documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/nnet/gs/classify-patterns-with-a-neural-network.html) states:

> Then arrange another set of Q target vectors so that they indicate the classes to which the input vectors are assigned

Here, we need a set of `Q=3` target vectors, which are `1` if a training sample belongs to that class. In your example, the target matrix looks like this:

```
T =

     1     0     0
     1     0     0
     1     0     0
     1     0     0
     1     0     0
     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     1     0
     0     1     0
     0     1     0
     0     1     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
     0     0     1
     0     0     1
     0     0     1
     0     0     1
     0     0     1
```

The first column corresponds to small, the second to medium and the third to large vehicles. You can generate this matrix from your existing cell array `Y` by using `cellfun` to compare the entries to the strings `'smallvehicle'` and so on:

```
T = [ cellfun(@(x)strcmp(x,'smallvehicle'),Y)   , ...
      cellfun(@(x)strcmp(x,'mediumvehicle'),Y)  , ...
      cellfun(@(x)strcmp(x,'largevehicle'),Y)   ];
```

Then you can start

```
nprtool
```

and use `X` as input and `T` as target. Remember to select `Matrix Rows` and not `Matrix columns`. The summary on the right helps: "Inputs 'X' is a 18x4 matrix, representing static data: 18 samples of 4 elements".

Comment: Thanks for this insight. Now how can the trained network be used to predict unseen data by stating the class of the vehicle. It is returning a matrix instead which I don't understand.

Comment: The output of `y=sim(net,someNewInput)` should be a 3x1 vector, which contains the outputs of the net for this input. The highest value will be your class (e.g. `[0.99 0.01 0]` will be a small vehicle). If this doesn't help, please ask a new question with details on what function you call, what your input is, and what the net returns (and what you expect).

Comment: Thanks for your response and help. Using the trained network on a new vehicle,XL, gave the following matrix. First  of all XL = [4.3569    3.3396    4.5793    6.1457] , then, sim(net,XL) = [0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000;  0.0845    0.1116    0.0773    0.0288;     0.9155    0.8884    0.9227    0.9712]. What does this matrix mean? Thanks a lot for the help.